# Dual graphic (between graphic card and mainboard graphic)

Tags: ati, graphics, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

Can I do the dual graphic (use two same monitor, the monitor 1 is next to monitor 2, monitor 1 use the graphic card, monitor 2 the mainboard graphic) on Ubuntu? What driver I should install to do the dual graphic?

> Mainboard graphic: HD2500 (from Intel Core i5-3450)
>   
> Graphic card: ATi Radeon HD 4850

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in my case, no you can't.

First, using multiple different vendor graphics cards, while theoretically possible, is riddled with problems.
*This part has been asked before, but I can't seem to put my hands on the question*

Second, most of the time on-board graphics is disabled when the motherboard detects a secondary video card inserted.

Third, even if it were possible you would run in to similar issues to what vga_switcheroo, bumblebee, and ironhide all try to address.

While they are a little different since they address hybrid graphics cards, I would imagine there would be similar problems.